# How to count records by week from specific data frame using SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Start Date: 10/14/2016
End Date: Statdate - 4 Weeks

I need a single query that does this sequence in SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName
    WHERE AddDate between  '10/14/2016 10:16:00' and '10/14/2016 10:31:00'

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName
    WHERE AddDate between  '10/07/2016 10:16:00' and '10/07/2016 10:31:00'

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName
    WHERE AddDate between  '09/30/2016 10:16:00' and '09/30/2016 10:31:00'

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName
    WHERE AddDate between  '09/23/2016 10:16:00' and '09/23/2016 10:31:00'
```

I would appreciate if someone help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this (for MySQL, but similar exists for other DBs)

```
SELECT 
DATE(AddDate) as TheDate,
COUNT(*) as Records
FROM TableName
WHERE
AddDate BETWEEN '2016-23-09' AND '2016-10-15'
AND DAYOFWEEK(AddDate) = 1 //for SUNDAYS
AND TIME(AddDate) BETWEEN '10:16:00' AND '10:31:00'
GROUP BY DATE(AddDate)
ORDER BY DATE(AddDate) ASC
```

I haven't tested this, but it should give you something like:

```
TheDates    Records
--------------------
2016-09-23    120
2016-09-30    157
...etc
```

Comment: You'll need to use [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) if you're on SQL Server instead of the date and time functions I used in my example.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 and abover:

Comment: I modified the statement to support SQL Server

Comment: SELECT CONVERT(Date, AddDate) as TheDate,
COUNT(*) as Records
FROM TableName WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
CONVERT(Date, AddDate)  BETWEEN '09/23/2016' AND '10/23/2016'
AND  DATEPART(dw,AddDate)=6 
AND CONVERT(Time, AddDate) BETWEEN '10:16:00' AND '10:31:00'
GROUP BY CONVERT(Date, AddDate)
ORDER BY CONVERT(Date, AddDate) ASC

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use UNION to put them all together? Or are you asking for something else?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName
    WHERE AddDate between  '10/14/2016 10:16:00' and '10/14/2016 10:31:00'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName
    WHERE AddDate between  '10/07/2016 10:16:00' and '10/07/2016 10:31:00'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName
    WHERE AddDate between  '09/30/2016 10:16:00' and '09/30/2016 10:31:00'
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName
    WHERE AddDate between  '09/23/2016 10:16:00' and '09/23/2016 10:31:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Group by

```
SELECT 
LEFT(DATENAME(wk,AddDate),2) as WeekNumber , 
COUNT(*) as Count 
FROM TableName
WHERE AddDate between  '09/23/2016 10:16:00' and '10/14/2016 10:31:00'
GROUP BY LEFT(DATENAME(wk,AddDate),2)
```

Comment: This returns the whole week data.

Comment: Ya, it's give count of each week which way you want output

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using `CASE` statement

```
SELECT ranges,count(*)
FROM   (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN AddDate BETWEEN '10/14/2016 10:16:00' AND '10/14/2016 10:31:00' THEN '10/14/2016 10:16:00 - 10/14/2016 10:31:00'
                 WHEN AddDate BETWEEN '10/07/2016 10:16:00' AND '10/07/2016 10:31:00' THEN '10/07/2016 10:16:00 - 10/07/2016 10:31:00'
                 WHEN AddDate BETWEEN '09/30/2016 10:16:00' AND '09/30/2016 10:31:00' THEN '09/30/2016 10:16:00 - 09/30/2016 10:31:00'
                 WHEN AddDate BETWEEN '09/23/2016 10:16:00' AND '09/23/2016 10:31:00' THEN '09/23/2016 10:16:00 - 09/23/2016 10:31:00'
               END AS ranges
        FROM   yourtable) a
GROUP  BY ranges
```